# Segmentation fault in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that checks palindrome.
But somehow I get a segmentation fault.
This program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int palindrome(char *beginning); //functions declaration

int main()
{
    char str[255],c; //variables
    int i=0;

    printf("please enter a string: "); //message to user 
    fgets(str,255,stdin);
    palindrome(str[255]);

    return 0;
}

int palindrome(char *beginning) //functions to chack palindrome  
{

    char *end = beginning + strlen(beginning) -1;

    if (end - beginning <= 0)
        return 1;

    if (!isalpha(*beginning))
        palindrome(beginning+1);

    if (!isalpha(*end))
        {
            *end = '\0';
            palindrome(beginning);
        }        

    if (*beginning == *end)
        {
            *end = '\0';
            return palindrome(beginning+1);
        }
    return 0;   

}
```

Comment: Check your compiler warnings. `palindrome(str[255])` is wrong. The function expects `char*`, but `str[255]` is a `char` and also accesses outside the array.

Comment: Did your compiler tell you anything of interest when you tried compiling this? If yes, *what* did it say? If not, get a standard-conforming compiler.

Answer (score 0):

`char str[255]` holds 255 values. With `palindrome(str[255]);` you attempt to pass the 256th(!) value of `str`, which doesn't exist.

What's more, `palindrome` accepts a `char *`, *pointer* to `char`, but you're passing a `char`, which'll lead to a bunch of other errors. You're probably looking for <strike>`&str[254]`</strike> or, as pointed out in the comments, merely `palindrome(str)`, which is more likely.

Comment: He's just looking for `palindrom(str);`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

Firstly, if you're trying to pass a `char []` array to a function, just pass the array name itself, i.e. (`function(array)`); passing `array[index]` is passing the value at the specific index you include.  Since the index you mention `255` is actually out of bounds of the array, you are accessing a value that isn't even in your array - even if you were calling a function that accepted a single `char` as an argument, this would be incorrect.

I wouldn't implement `palindrome` to be recursive unless it's a specific requirement for your assignment/coursework. Technically, this is all you need for a palindrome test (you may omit the parameter `len` and call `strlen` in your function to determine the length if you wish):

```
int ispalindrome(char *str, int len)
{   
    char *p = &str[0];
    char *q = &str[len - 1];
    do
    {
        if(p >= q)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    while (*p++ == *q--);
    return 0;
}
```